# Where is the location of file created by Cordova File Plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have used [Cordova File Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file) to create files on mobile device. Below is the code to create files:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (dir) {
   alert(cordova.file.dataDirectory);
   dir.getFile("log.txt", { create: true }, function (file) {
          alert("got the file: "+ file.name + ', ' + file.fullPath);
   });
});
```

When I deploy the app on my android phone, the file will create successfully, but I can't find the created file on my device.

Although `cordova.file.dataDirectory` is pointing to  `file:///data/data/io.cordova.myappId/files/` path on my device, the `io.cordova.myappId` folder doesn't exist in `data>data` path, but exists in `Android>data` path. By the way, I checked both `storage>Android>data>io.Cordova.myappId>files` & `storage>data>data` and the file doesn't exist.

Is this because:

The created file is located in another place, so where can I find that?

or

Because it's private and my file manager doesn't have access to it, so how can I change the permission setting to have a public file?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Why I can't find the file on my device?**

The file is created successfully but I can't find that on my device because the `dataDirectory` path which I indicates to create the file, is a private path and my device file manager doesn't have access to it (base on [this table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout)). Actually `dataDirectory` is an `Internal Storage` option.

> Internal Storage: Store private data on the device memory.
>
> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By
>   default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.([reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal))

**How to create a public file?**

So, to create a file on my device that I can access it with the file manager, I have to use one of public path options like:`externalDataDirectory`. Before, I was thinking it is for storing files on an external SD Card that I had not on my phone, so I didn't test it. But testing it today, it creates the file on my internal device storage in `Android/data/<app-id>/files` path which is public and I can access it with device file manager.

Actually the term `internal` and `external` was misleading for me while `external storage` can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage([reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)).

Comment: Hi @A.M, i facing the similar issue. Though i use externalDataDirectory, i am unable to find my file in the device. Function getFile returns success. Am i missing anything else. Please help.

Comment: @Aish123 I don't have your code so I can't tell you if something is missed or not. Just can tell you this will work:  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function (dirEntry) { dirEntry.getDirectory(dirName, { create: true }, function (dirEntry) {  dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {alert("Create the file: " + fileEntry.name + ', ' + fileEntry.fullPath);});
                    }, errorHandler)
                }, errorHandler);

Comment: @Aish123 Also check the other r/w paths base on [this table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout) if your device is android or check other tables based on your device OS.

Comment: Thanks for reply @A.M. I have used externalRootDirectory but the file got created in internal storage though the callback shows external memory as path. All i want is to create a file for checking logs and i got it. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: @A.M: Thanks to you. I was facing this issue yesterday when I updated my phonegap version from 5.x.x to 6.3.0. Somewhere between these versions the behaviour has to be changed, because with version 5.x.x I received the path from device storage with `dataDirectory`.

Comment: I only see the file generated on the phone, but not on the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Reading/wiring files in Cordova is painful. I wrote a script that uses promises to make this easier.

Add [cordova-file-storage.js](https://github.com/john-doherty/cordova-file-storage) to your project, then do the following:

```js
// the object you want to save
var objectToSave = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doherty' };

// the filename and extension you want to use
var filename = 'whatever.txt';

// the data to write (convert JSON object to a string)
var data = JSON.stringify(objectToSave);

// call write with params, .then executes with the filePath once complete
fileStorage.write(filename, data).then(function(filePath) {
     console.log(filePath);
})
.catch(function(err) {
     // this executes if something went wrong
     console.warn(err);
});
```

It uses external storage by default. To use sandboxed storage inaccessible to the user add `true` as the last param.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Thanks @Will, it's now fixed

Comment: Still getting a github 404 error on that link.

Comment: Apologies, it was private :-| sorted now